# transfer files from an Android device to Windows PC via wifi on same LAN

Tags: android, android-wifi

I've googled it but no success...trying to find a way which I can transfer files from my Android app to a Windows PC on the same LAN, to a shared folder on the PC. it has to be done via wifi, and must not be depended on other app. therefore the solution has to be coded.

Thanks in advance,
Kfir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use socket programming in android to send file to pc by IP.
if you create share folder in your windows pc by r/w permission , use JCIFS for samba share.

ES file manager use JCIFS library for LAN sharing.

Comment: @Kfir : Can you please tell me how you did it? Using Sockets or using JCIFS. The resources and examples for JCIFS are very less.Could you share how you did it.

Comment: @TheCuriousDev Sure, but this topic is closed so I cannot post the code....is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

I use an app called ES file manager, free.

It has a panel for LAN where you can scan and add computers on the same LAN, or manually. To be allowed access to your PC, you have to have in the PC an user which has password, even if the user is not logged in.

Then you can cut and paste files to/from any device in the LAN.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I know this app. This is not what I'm looking for. My app must send files independently so I have to code it.

Comment: @Kfir It is not clear in your question. You should edit the question to make it clear and also add a tag for the coding language you intend to use.